# Gps location is null

Tags: android, gps, osmdroid, android-gps

I am trying to make an app that gave me the position in a `TextView` but the result if I enable Fine location is `null`:

```
public class Gpslocation extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpslocation);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location position = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

       //LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

        String message_gps = "gps position : "+position;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtgpscoord);
        textView.setText(message_gps);

    }
}
```

If I set fake coordinates with the app "Fake Location" on my phone it gaves me a result, but not without it. But my Gps works well with other applications so the problem is clearly comming from my code.

If I uncomment this line with :  `//LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);` the application crashes...

I put the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

Thanks you very much in advance for your help.

EDIT: logcat is :

```
04-19 15:25:47.388 19663-19663/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-19 15:25:47.414 19663-19663/? E/art: Failed to send JDWP packet APNM to debugger (-1 of 57): Broken pipe
04-19 15:25:47.414 19663-19670/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-19 15:25:47.414 19663-19670/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-19 15:25:47.515 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:47.770 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:47.841 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:47.902 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:47.964 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.029 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.099 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.161 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.225 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.288 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.350 19663-19663/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@test.testgpspos-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-19 15:25:48.352 19663-19663/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/test.testgpspos-2/lib/arm
04-19 15:25:48.353 19663-19663/? I/srstest: makeApplication sAppContextandroid.app.Application@f0af218
04-19 15:25:48.353 19663-19663/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=test.testgpspos
04-19 15:25:48.355 19663-19663/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-19 15:25:48.359 19663-19663/? D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{82bd256 test.testgpspos}}
04-19 15:25:48.359 19663-19663/? V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}} startsNotResumed=false
04-19 15:25:48.423 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@f0af218, appName=test.testgpspos, pkg=test.testgpspos, comp={test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/base.apk
04-19 15:25:48.424 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/PackageManager: Query text for package: test.testgpsposresid: 2131099681
04-19 15:25:48.425 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/fiona: ApplicationPackageManager line1356 text=testgpspos
04-19 15:25:48.425 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/fiona: ApplicationPackageManager line1358=test.testgpspos
04-19 15:25:48.425 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/fiona: ApplicationPackageManager line1359=READY,ABSENT
04-19 15:25:48.461 19663-19663/test.testgpspos W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-19 15:25:48.504 19663-19663/test.testgpspos E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
04-19 15:25:48.535 19663-19672/test.testgpspos I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
04-19 15:25:48.661 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}
04-19 15:25:48.673 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}
04-19 15:25:48.673 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
04-19 15:25:48.673 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a8860a9 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-19 15:25:48.676 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a8860a9 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@ca312f2
04-19 15:25:48.677 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 4 threads <0xabf70280>
04-19 15:25:48.678 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: <test.testgpspos> is running.
04-19 15:25:48.679 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
04-19 15:25:48.680 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb3145800
04-19 15:25:48.683 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{a60fd43 test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity,ident = 0}
04-19 15:25:48.687 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
04-19 15:25:48.687 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{a60fd43 test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a8860a9 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-19 15:25:48.687 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}
04-19 15:25:48.687 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}
04-19 15:25:48.731 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb3145800 initialize window=0xae406608, title=test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity
04-19 15:25:48.731 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xae406600)
04-19 15:25:48.737 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-19 15:25:48.739 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0xae411480)
04-19 15:25:48.741 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: Get enable program binary service property (1)
04-19 15:25:48.741 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
04-19 15:25:48.742 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
04-19 15:25:48.742 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
04-19 15:25:48.743 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
04-19 15:25:48.743 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
04-19 15:25:48.743 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 171416, program map length is 152.
04-19 15:25:48.744 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 46, and path is /dev/ashmem.
04-19 15:25:48.744 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(46).
04-19 15:25:48.744 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0xb6d27eac, size = 4
04-19 15:25:48.747 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000000)
04-19 15:25:48.748 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000800000003)
04-19 15:25:48.750 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000500040)
04-19 15:25:48.751 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000003800000000)
04-19 15:25:48.751 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xae406600,api=1)
04-19 15:25:48.752 19663-19721/test.testgpspos W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
04-19 15:25:48.753 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-19 15:25:48.777 19663-19663/test.testgpspos W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-19 15:25:48.790 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 1 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 111, 166
04-19 15:25:48.798 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x9fa78500), client(48), share_fd(47)
04-19 15:25:48.798 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x9fa78500) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:48.800 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache save to disk, size = 4
04-19 15:25:48.804 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
04-19 15:25:48.804 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a8860a9 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@212ce97 controlFlags=#104
04-19 15:25:48.817 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x9fa78640), client(48), share_fd(50)
04-19 15:25:48.817 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x9fa78640) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.667 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 4 != cached 0
04-19 15:25:56.668 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@9635e69, holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@44960ee
04-19 15:25:56.670 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x9fa78780), client(48), share_fd(51)
04-19 15:25:56.670 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x9fa78780) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.682 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}
04-19 15:25:56.688 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad
04-19 15:25:56.690 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}} startsNotResumed=false
04-19 15:25:56.705 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}}: app=android.app.Application@f0af218, appName=test.testgpspos, pkg=test.testgpspos, comp={test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}, dir=/data/app/test.testgpspos-2/base.apk
04-19 15:25:56.706 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/PackageManager: Query text for package: test.testgpsposresid: 2131099681
04-19 15:25:56.706 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/fiona: ApplicationPackageManager line1288 text=testgpspos
04-19 15:25:56.710 19663-19663/test.testgpspos E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
04-19 15:25:56.726 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}}
04-19 15:25:56.727 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}}
04-19 15:25:56.727 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
04-19 15:25:56.727 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f74608 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-19 15:25:56.727 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f74608 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@ca312f2
04-19 15:25:56.728 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xae85b000
04-19 15:25:56.729 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{cd9ff50 test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation,ident = 1}
04-19 15:25:56.732 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}} with isForward=true
04-19 15:25:56.732 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{cd9ff50 test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation,ident = 1}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f74608 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-19 15:25:56.732 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}}
04-19 15:25:56.732 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{ce0041c token=android.os.BinderProxy@64a7825 {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}}
04-19 15:25:56.756 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xa81b6e00)
04-19 15:25:56.758 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xae85b000 initialize window=0xa81b6e08, title=test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation
04-19 15:25:56.758 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xa81b6e00,api=1)
04-19 15:25:56.759 19663-19721/test.testgpspos W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
04-19 15:25:56.759 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-19 15:25:56.769 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 1 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 43, 113, 174
04-19 15:25:56.773 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x9fa78c80), client(48), share_fd(54)
04-19 15:25:56.773 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x9fa78c80) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.783 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
04-19 15:25:56.783 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f74608 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@825481 controlFlags=#104
04-19 15:25:56.797 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x9fa78dc0), client(48), share_fd(49)
04-19 15:25:56.797 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x9fa78dc0) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.803 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xae406600,api=1)
04-19 15:25:56.804 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x9fa78500) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.805 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0x9fa78500), client(48), share_fd(47)
04-19 15:25:56.805 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x9fa78640) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.806 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0x9fa78640), client(48), share_fd(50)
04-19 15:25:56.806 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x9fa78780) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-19 15:25:56.807 19663-19721/test.testgpspos I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0x9fa78780), client(48), share_fd(51)
04-19 15:25:56.807 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xae406600,api=1)
04-19 15:25:56.808 19663-19721/test.testgpspos D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xaa66dc00 (RippleDrawable @12d1bb) with handle 0xb4675c20
04-19 15:25:56.974 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{942f2d7 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad {test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@a037926
04-19 15:25:56.975 19663-19663/test.testgpspos V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =ViewRoot{a60fd43 test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a8860a9 I.E...... R......D 0,0-720,1280}
04-19 15:25:56.975 19663-19663/test.testgpspos D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@7506ad
```

Edit #2: If I add the following code for requestLocationUpdates :

```
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
        Location position = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

I get the following logcat :

```
4-19 23:04:35.971 16384-16384/test.testgpspos E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
04-19 23:04:35.986 16384-16384/test.testgpspos D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-19 23:04:35.987 16384-16384/test.testgpspos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: test.testgpspos, PID: 16384
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.testgpspos/test.testgpspos.Gpslocation}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.testgpspos.Gpslocation cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.testgpspos.Gpslocation cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
                                                                     at test.testgpspos.Gpslocation.onCreate(Gpslocation.java:40)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
04-19 23:04:36.005 16384-16393/test.testgpspos I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
```

Probably I did something wrong with the syntax...

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: There is no crash if I don't let locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this); commented.

Comment: What do you mean by crash log ? If you mean the logcat it is too long for posting here...

Comment: So how are you saying that it is  not working

Comment: Long is fine but it will show the exact issue.

Comment: Sorry its really to long I cannot post it fully

Comment: It is not crashing but position = null instead of the gps coordinates

Comment: I was asking you to post with question itself not in comments

Comment: I added the logcat in the message as you requested. Thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null if there is no last known location, e.g. when starting the app for the first time. This is perfectly fine. If `requestLocationUpdates()` crashes then you have to provide the exception and crash log to us.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the message with the logcat with requestLocationUpdates(). I suppose I did something wrong but I don't know what... Thanks for your help

Comment: Any idea ? Is the syntax of my code for requestLocationUpdates ok ?

Comment: help me please !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this lane:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
```

As you can see in the log, you cannot cast Gpslocation class to LocationListener. The Gpslocation class needs to implement LocationListener so the solution would be to change the class declaration to:

```
public class Gpslocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
```